# set an option of select selected by value = value from backend

Tags: javascript, vert.x

i'm newbie to vertx toolkit. i have **a table** and **a combobox** in my peb file :

```
<select id="status">
   <option value="1">active</option>
   <option value="0">deactive</option>
</select>
```

in the `tbody` of the table, i want to add that tag to a `td` by `outerHTML` like this :

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "my/url",
        success: function (data) {
            var rowsTxt = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var d = data[i];
                var r = '<tr id="'+ d["bill_id"] +  '">' +
                    '<td><input type="checkbox" class="minimal" 
                                   onIfChanged="update_btn_class()"/></td>' +
                    '<td>' + d["user_name"] + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d["pass"] + '</
                    '<td>' + document.getElementById("status").outerHTML + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + d["time_create"] + '</td>';
```

now i need this combobox has value equal to the value from the database. how can i do that ???
Thanks very much !

Comment: `$("#status").val(valueFromBackend)`

Comment: yes i tried that, i put it into for loop. it didn't work.

Comment: There can only be on `#status` combobox, you shouldn't do it in the loop.

Comment: `data` is an array, which of them is the value that you want to use in the combobox?

Comment: I think if you don't get select html and add to string, you can check value and add `selected` to option.

Comment: my data includes : d["bill"], d["user_name"], d["pass"], d["status"],d["time_create"]. and i want eacch of my d["status"] showed in comboboxes.
(i'm sorry if my english is bad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element IDs need to be unique, you can't use `id="status"` in every row of the table.

You need to clone the `#status` element, remove the ID, and assign it the value you want.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "my/url",
  success: function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      var row = $("<td>", {
        id: d.bill_id
      });
      row.append($('<td><input type="checkbox" class="minimal" onIfChanged = "update_btn_class()"/></td>'));
      row.append($('<td>', {
        text: d.user_name
      }));
      var combo = $("#status").clone().removeAttr('id');
      combo.val(d.status);
      var comboTd = $("<td>");
      comboTd.append(combo);
      row.append(comboTd);
      row.append($("<td>", {
        text: d.time_create
      }));
      $("#table").append(row);
    });
  }
});
```